# Apache folders mapped to urls

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have folder structure like this:

```
-- /var/www/domain
|
|-- wordpress
|-- framework
```

The desired functionality is when you go to domain.com its "document root" is in `wordpress` folder.

When you open domain.com/embed "document root" would be in `framework` folder.

I think the biggest problem is that I still need to support canonical URLS inside both of those folders.

Some example urls for wordpress are:

```
domain.com/contact
domain.com/solutions/finance
domain.com/blog/something-happened-yesterday (this might be subdomain blog.domain.com - not decided yet)
```

Embed will be always in format:

```
domain.com/embed/Category/Item?some=1,params=0
```

Wordpress and framework code is 100% independent  of each other.

I think if I would simply move `framework` folder into `wordpress` folder and named it "embed" it would probably save a lot of trouble and work pretty well. But I feel like it's not a good solution, and would prefer to keep them separate as they are now.

Some more snippets:

I tried many apache configurations, this is one of them:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName u.ipushpull.com
    ServerAdmin admin@ipushpull.com    

    DocumentRoot /var/www/ipushpull.com/u/wordpress
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html    

    Alias /embed/ /var/www/ipushpull.com/u/framework/code/wwwroot/

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ipushpull_web_u_access.log combined
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ipushpull_web_u_error.log
    LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
```

The .htaccess in framework folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: why is alias not working? i used this in a similar setup (edit: maybe the trailing slash?)

Comment: @RaphaelMüller The alias did work (yes without the slash) but only for the root /embed . if I do /embed/something/somehting, it just throws 404

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found solution.

After looking into logs I noticed errors that were looking for files where they shouldn't be. And after more time googling finally I found something useful.

In your htaccess you **MUST** setup RewriteBase to whatever first parameter of your Alias is.

My final setting:

**Apache Virtual Host**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName u.ipushpull.com
    ServerAdmin admin@ipushpull.com

    Alias /embed /var/www/ipushpull.com/u/framework/code/wwwroot        

    <Directory "/var/www/ipushpull.com/u/framework/code/wwwroot">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/ipushpull.com/u/wordpress
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ipushpull_web_u_access.log combined
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ipushpull_web_u_error.log
    LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
```

**.htaccess (in framework/code/wwwroot)**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /embed
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Works like a charm